Unable to Retrieve Phone Number Hint in Android Java
I am attempting to implement the Phone Number Hint feature in my Android application using Java. However, every time I execute the code, the process falls into the addOnFailureListener callback. Below is the code snippet I am working with:
ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(
                    new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
                    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                            try {
                                String phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(Register.this).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.getData());
                                ed_number.setText(phoneNumber);
                            } catch (ApiException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });

    private void requestPhoneNumberHint() {
        GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest request = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build();

        Identity.getSignInClient(Register.this)
                .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(request)
                .addOnSuccessListener(result -> {
                    try {
                        IntentSenderRequest req = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result).build();
                        phoneNumberHintIntentResultLauncher.launch(req);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("===", "Launching the PendingIntent failed");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("===", "Phone Number Hint failed"+"\n"+e.getMessage()+"\n"));
    }

When I run this code, the log consistently shows the following error message:
Phone Number Hint failed
16: [28438] No phone number is found on this device.

Reference:
I referred to the implementation guidelines from the following resource: Google Developers - Phone Number Hint.
Questions

Why is the Phone Number Hint API unable to detect a phone number, and how can I resolve this issue?


Welcome to Stack Overflow--questions here must ask one thing, not multiple. Please edit your question to ask only one question, otherwise this risks being closed as needing focus. Oh, and make sure your question is objectively answerable. Questions soliciting opinions (like asking how to do something "gracefully") are off-topic here as well.

Does the device have a phone number?  Tablets don't.  ANd even for phones, not all devices know their own number (it's weird, and a legacy of how some SIM cards are setup-  the device doesn't need to know its own number to work, so sometimes they aren't told it).

@GabeSechan - Yes, my device(Samsung M31s) has a SIM available still shows No phone number is found on this device.

Doesn't matter if it HAS a sim.  Not all sims know their own phone number.  The network doesn't require it, because it could be a data only SIM.  Even if it is a phone SIM, it still doesn't need its own number programmed in.

Previously, I was using Android Gradle version 7.5 and AGP version 7.4.2, where I consistently encountered the error:
Phone Number Hint failed 16: [28438] No phone number is found on this device.
This happened on all devices.
After updating to Gradle version 8.7 and AGP version 8.5.0, the issue was resolved for most devices, and the Phone Number Hint pop-up started working properly. However, the same error still occurs on a specific device, Samsung M31s, while it works as expected on other devices.
